# What 'limit point' means in $\Bbb Z_+\times {\{a,b}\}$?

Tags: general-topology

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/512393/why-is-the-set-mathbbz-times-a-b-limit-point-compact/512405#512405) was a question, but raised another question of meaning of a neighborhood. According to the answer:

> [Let] $Y=\{a,b\}$. If $S$ is a subset of $\Bbb Z_+\times Y$ and $(n,a)\in S$, then $(n,b)$ is a limit point of $S.$ Conversely, if $(n,b)\in S$, then $(n,a)$ is a limit point of $S.$.

I know two 'application' of the definition of limit point:

1. in the standard topology, the way to recognize whether a point as a limit point is to have an arbitrary $(a,b)$ including the limit point to know if the $(a,b)$ intersects other points of the set also;
2. in case of $A={\{a,b,...}\}$, although ${\{a,b}\}$ is a neighborhood of $a$, but ${\{a}\}$ is itself also is a neighborhood of $a$. Having said that, since ${\{a}\}$ doesn't include other points in addition to $a$, so no element/point of $A={\{a,b,...}\}$ is limit point since not **every** neighborhood intersects $A$ in another point.

So is for the case of $\Bbb Z_+\times Y$. Since $(n,b)\in S$ is also a neighborhood of $(n,b)$, why then $(n,a)$ is a limit point of $S$?

Forgive me if my question is disappointing, but I am a beginner in topology.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the topology on $\{a,b\}$?

Comment: @Asaf Karagila: discrete topology.

Comment: If you look at the question you will see it is the *indiscrete* topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the question itself, not just the answer, you will see that the topology on $\{a,b\}$ is indiscrete. Namely, the only open sets are $\varnothing$ and $\{a,b\}$.

So what are the open sets in the product? They are either empty, or unions of sets of the form $U\times\{a,b\}$ when $U$ is open in $\Bbb Z_+$.

So now if $(n,a)$ is an element of $S$, then for every open set which includes $(n,b)$, this open set must also include $(n,a)$. Therefore this open set intersects $S$ nontrivially.

Comment: So $\Bbb Z_+\times {\{a,b}\}$ won't be limit point compact in discrete topology. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: You're welcome!